# Oracle Connectors v4.0 is not working for SSIS

Tags: oracle, ssis

I upgrade SSDT from 2012 to 2017 recently, the package containing a Oracle source and a Oracle destination run well before upgrading.

After upgrading, it has error:

```
The component metadata for oracle source, clsid{....} could not be upgraded to new version of the component, The perform upgrade method failed.
```

I guess it may be related to Oracle connector version, so I download connector 4.0 from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52950

But even I install connector 4.0 and rebuild my SSIS package containing Oracle connection manager, the error is same as before, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for 2 days and it can be resolved by installing connector 5.0(though 5.0 is for SQL Server 2017, but my SQL Server is 2016).